How can celery use Django ORM?
How can celery use Django ORM?
Celery and django are diffent processes.
But, Celery worker can use Django Application code.(ORM, Model..)
I think celery process have django application code. Is it right?
What should I do setting when django and celery on another server physically?
I was wondering how Celery can use the code in the django.

The server where the Celery workers run on still needs to have the task code (likely your application), even if it's not running a web/application server to serve pages to clients.
Then, it's just an issue of configuring your Django DATABASES setting on the Celery-worker running box so it's able to connect to the same database (and caches, etc., as necessary).
